# Struct to IEEE754

Tags: c, ieee-754

my question concerns IEEE 754 single percision numbers. 
Suppose I have a struct:

```
typedef struct __ieee754
{ 
   int sign;
   int exponent;
   int mantissa;
} IEEE754,*pIEEE754;
```

Can I convert that to a single percision (1-8-23 float) number? I am using C.

Comment: The identifier `__ieee754` (as all identifiers starting with `__`) is reserved for the implementation. I suggest you use another name for portability sake.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing your implementation uses IEEE 754 single precision numbers for `float`, something like this should work

```
struct __ieee754 f;
/* set f to something valid */
float x = f.sign * f.mantissa * pow(2, f.exponent);
```

Comment: `ldexpf(f.mantissa, f.exponent)` might be a better idea than `f.mantissa * pow(2, f.exponent)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming 32-bit `unsigned int` and IEEE-754 single precision `float` type:

```
union bla {
    unsigned int a;
    float b;
};

union bla num = {
        (((unsigned int) f.sign & 1) << 31)
      | (((unsigned int) f.exponent & 0xFF) << 23)
      | ( (unsigned int) f.mantissa & 0x7FFFFF); 
};

printf("%f\n", num.b)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your shifts and masks for the exponent and mantissa are off. And you can't just assign it to a `float`. You need to pass the bits over via a `union` or something of that sort.

Comment: @Mysticial yes, many errors in the first version, thank you for the remark.

Comment: There's still an error - the exponent needs to be biased to remove negatives, and the implicit leading 1 in the mantissa needs to be accounted for.  Unless the input structure has done this, in which case @pmg's answer is incorrect.

Comment: @AShelly this is a good remark. Let say I assumed the `exponent` struct member is the IEEE-754 `exponent`, otherwise I agree the exponent bias has to be accounted for to be correct.

Comment: After looking at the definition again, I suspect your assumption is correct, but the question is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

One of the previous two answers must be incorrect - because the question is underspecified.   We need to know if the structure contains the binary representation of the IEEE float components, or if it contains a numeric definition.

Based on the fact that they are integers, the first is more likely:   -4.2 would be represented as `{1,0x81,0x066666}` or `0xC0866666`.  In this case, @ouah's answer is correct, and @pmg's will give 2.85e44.

On the other hand, in order for @pmg's code to be correct, the struct for -4.2 would be have to be stored as `{-1,-21,0x433333}`.  And then applying @ouah's algorithm gives `0xF5C33333` which is -4.9489e32 when interpreted as an IEEE float.

If we assume that you are using the first representation, then there is a non-portable processor trick which can simplify your code.  Redefine your struct as a union as follows.

```
union flt  {  
    struct ieee754 {
       unsigned int mantissa:23;
       unsigned int exponent:8;
       unsigned int sign:1;
    } raw;
    float f;
 }
```

(You might need to reverse the order of arguments depending on your procesor - and ensure the packing is correct - that's the non-portable part)

Now your code can write directly to the memory as bits and read it back as floats:

```
  union flt num;
  num.raw.sign = 1;
  num.raw.exponent = 129;
  num.raw.mantissa = 0x66666;
  printf("%f", num.f);  //prints 4.2
```

Comment: +1, personnally for portability reasons I tend to always avoid bit-fields (almost everything is implementation defined when dealing with bit-fields) but you have nice points in your answer.